# productid is not saving in vendor database

Tags: database, laravel

The productid in my vendors table in the database is not saving, 
this is my vendor database
[image: vendorend.png]
This is the vendor database structure 
[image: vendordb.png]
This is my product table in the database 
[image: productend.png]
This is the product database structure
[image: productdb.png]

The product and Vendor tables have an eloquent relationship between them.

This is the product model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['title', 'category', 'tags', 'description','sizes', 'price', 'previous_price', 'stock', 'feature_image', 'policy', 'featured', 'views', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'status'];

public static $withoutAppends = false;




public function vendor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Vendors', 'productid', 'id');
}

public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order', 'products');
}
```

This is the vendor model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Vendors extends Authenticatable
 {
     use Notifiable;
public $table = "vendor_profiles";
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'gender', 'email', 'shop_name', 'photo', 'phone', 'password', 'fax', 'address', 'city', 'zip', 'current_balance', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
];

 public function product()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product',  'vendorid', 'id');
}

public function orderven()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order', 'vendorid');
}
}
```

I want to echo the product title uploaded by the vendor in this blade view

```
@section('content')

<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" id="main">
            <!-- Page Heading -->
            <div class="go-title">
               <h3>Vendors</h3>
                <div class="go-line"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Page Content -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="response">
                        @if(Session::has('message'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                                {{ Session::get('message') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="10%">ID#</th>
                            <th>Vendor Name</th>
                            <th>Vendor Email</td>
                            <th>Vendor City</td>
                             <th>Products</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                    @foreach($vendors as $vendor)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$vendor->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$vendor->name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$vendor->email}}</td>
                            <td>{{$vendor->city}}</td>
                            <td>@if(is_null($vendor->productid)) No Product @else {{$vendor->product->id}} @endif</td>



                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
<!-- /#page-wrapper -->

@stop

@section('footer')

@stop
```

This is the page
[image: table.png]

The productid in the vendors table is not saving to the database

Answer (score 0):

In your `Vendors` model, add `productid` in the `$fillable` array.

Comment: did that, it doesnt do any effect.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above, you can add the id to your `$fillable` but better option, you can use,
`$guarded`. Looks like your structure doesn't have a 'guarded' field. so you can use '$guarded'

Comment: you said it's not saving to db but where's your save function? how can we decide is your code correct or something missing. because the code you provided doesn't contain any kind of saving . just printing it out and you asked for it's not saving. fun

Comment: code is correct as you can see in the product table database screenshot, products are been saved in the products table.